# What is the method to return a numerical value instead of boolean in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, methods, boolean

Want to check whether a number is in a given range.

```
def ran_check(num,low,high):
    if num in range(low,high):
        print('{num} is not in the range of {low} and {high}')
    else:
        print('{num} is not in the range of {low} and {high}')
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is your return statement?

Comment: What kind of "numerical value" you want to return? 1 or 0? If so, why? Python has booleans

Answer (score 0):

Simly cast the boolean to integer and return it.

```
def ran_check(num, low, high):
    return int(num in range(low, high))
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this question clear, I think what he meant is test cases should return a boolean like this:

```
print(ran_check(3,1,10)) # Output: True
print(ran_check(11,1,10)) # Output: False
```

In this case, the easiest way to return a boolean in this function is:

```
def ran_check(num,low,high):
    return num in range(low,high + 1)
```

Upvote if I helped out to make it clear. Thanks!